# go-ethereum: Return data from contract function

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, abi, golang

I have a smart contract written in solidity.  I deployed the contract to my Ganache network and I can interact with it via go-ethereum using stubs generated by abigen.  My function returns a uint256, what I want to do is see this contract return data via the stubs I have generated with abigen.

I can successfully interact with the contract.  I just want to know how to use the returned `types.Transaction` to obtain what my contract function returns - I am guessing the decode 'instructions' are in the generated abi.  thanks

```
    instance, _ := tictac.NewTictac(address, client)

    privateKey, _ := crypto.HexToECDSA("1234")

    transactOpts := bind.NewKeyedTransactor(privateKey)
    publicKey := privateKey.Public()
    publicKeyECDSA, _ := publicKey.(*ecdsa.PublicKey)

    fromAddress := crypto.PubkeyToAddress(*publicKeyECDSA)

    gasPrice, _ := client.SuggestGasPrice(context.Background())

opts := &bind.TransactOpts{
    From:     fromAddress,
    Signer:   transactOpts.Signer,
    Value:    big.NewInt(1),
    GasPrice: gasPrice,
    GasLimit: 1000000,
}

    types, _ := instance.StartGame(opts, "player1", true, big.NewInt(1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Not possible yet. You can use Events